# Are RVs on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Many RV owners are expert amateurs, as seen on many RV message boards. Are their questions on-topic here on Travel?

Some RV issues are already covered by [Home Improvement SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) (e.g. plumbing, electrical) or by [Motor Vehicle SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) (suspension, tire pressure), but some are off topic for both (holding tanks, absorption fridges). Would the rest of RVing be on-topic for Travel?

If not, I'm [proposing an RV site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41354/recreational-vehicles).

Answer (score 5):

If it's a TRAVEL RV question, then by all means - where to park an RV in town X or Y, for example.

If it's a maintenance or repair or mechanical, like 'how to repair the gizmo G on model M' - then no - put it on MV like you said.

I'd actually do a RV propsal anyway, could be interesting to see how it goes.

Comment: Yep I'm with Mark. Travelling with an RV is 100% on topic. All the not travelling stuff about an RV is 100% off topic. But great idea for an SE site!